# Why Float return different value and how can i solve it, Java

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I am using `Float` to saving value. But when i save it seven and more then value in Float its return me different format value for example..

```
Float f=1234567.98
```

then float return me in string

```
1.23457e+06
```

What means of this and how can i solve it. Kindly please help me about this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `DecimalFormat` that uses for how many number want after your floating point

Comment: See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM04-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+numbers+if+precise+computation+is+required

Comment: Why are you using `float` in the first place? They don't *have* more than seven decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a decimal use:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

In this case the format you want is `###.##`
An example of using this would be

```
float f = 123456.78f;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##');
String formatted = format.format(f);
```

Note that if you are using this for monetary calculations you should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. Floats are an efficient way of storing real numbers, but they can only represent so many.  Here is an example of using BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(123456.78f);
bd = bd.add(3.4f);
bd = bd.divide(4.3f);//this division with floats may have returned an inexact answer
bd.setScale(2);//Makes sure we only care about 2 decimal places
String strValue = bd.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

It means one of two things. Either your preferred printing method only shows a certain number of digits by default, or you are requesting more precision than a `Float` offers. The [wikipedia page for single precision floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) says that you can expect 6-9 decimal digits will be represented accurately. So that's probably your problem. You should be able to solve it by using a `Double` to store your value and `DecimalFormat` to customize the output.